# Getting this issue while trying to host flask application on IIS

Tags: windows, flask, iis-7, fastcgi, wfastcgi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf1qH.png)

I was following this https://medium.com/@dpralay07/deploy-a-python-flask-application-in-iis-server-and-run-on-machine-ip-address-ddb81df8edf3

And i get this error when i add the environment variable both pythonpath and wsgi handler and when i press ok in Edit FastCGI Application this error appeared.

So can anyone has solution to this issue i have tried rebooting the server

Comment: You might read https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/ to get rid of wfastcgi first.

Comment: As Lex Li said, you can switch to HttpPlatformHandler.  FastCGI is no longer recommended by Microsoft, it has been deprecated. So this is no longer the correct way to host Python web applications on IIS. Reference link: https://medium.com/@akshay.mewada7/host-flask-and-django-web-application-with-windows-iis-httpplatformhanlder-83e831ce91bc